# How to clear check boxes after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Simply put, I have a series of videos with check boxes in a gridview.  After hitting submit, there is a postback, and they go to another gridview on the same page.  My question is simply this, how do I make the initial check boxes where the user first picks the videos be unchecked?  Every time a user hits the submit button after selecting a few videos the boxes stay checked and if you pick some more and hit enter without realizing the other ones were still checked you now have duplicate entries.

I am sorry for what I estimate is a simple answer, but all the research I have done deals with much more elaborate problems.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I am sorry, I should have mentioned this is in C# ASP.NET.  This is the check box in question:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbAdd" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code would at the end of the method which handles the submit button

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        var cb = row.FindControl("cbAdd") as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null)
           cb.Checked = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you may try disabling view state for them (quick and dirty)

Answer (score 1):

well you can always handle the check-boxes to be checked or unchecked after a specific event.
for example you have this check-box

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" checked="" />
```

so you can say if something happened, make this checked or unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" checked="<?php if(condition) echo 'checked'; ?>" />
```

or make it unchecked in the same way.

Comment: php? there are asp.net and C# tags in the question :)